# What's best way to know which branch & which workspace I'm working on

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using VS 2013 with TFS online. I have several branches and workspace.
When I open a solution, I cannot easily tell which branch and which workspace I'm in easily.

In old vs source safe, I can tell by Source control BIND. The current open solution is bound to a branch and workspace. Where can I get the info properly? Source Control Explorer, Team Explorer seems not good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research, I confirm that VS does not tell which branch you are working on.
You can do as timB33 does. But, this does not tell you that you are in which branch.
Team Explorer and Source Control Explorer shows identical for both solutions from different branches.

For sure, I do open folder by "Open Folder in File Explorer" on a project or solution. The folder path that I always setup with proper branch structure tells me 100% where I am.

I wish VS improve to display the current folder path or TFS path of 'Source Control Explorer' for the current project or solution on Title or Property or Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I organise my workspaces like this:

- C:_ws\tfs\collnZZ\dev\dev04
- C:_ws\tfs\collnZZ\fb\fb01
- C:_ws\tfs\collnZZ\main\main31

I also keep an eye on >TeamExplorer>SourceControlExplorer and then I look at Workspace and expect my local path (beneath workspace) to be mapped.